# How to read/load data into Azure DataBricks or Azure DataLake using Spring Batch?

Tags: azure, spring-batch, azure-data-lake

I am looking to Read from the csv/xml/Postgres DB and write into the Azure DataLake or DataBricks using Spring Batch. I dont see any API as for yet which does this. Anyone knows how can we do it using Spring batch?

Here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4074

Comment: Why this question has been closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature isn't available in Azure Databricks yet so you need to change your approach.

There is already a similar feature request in GitHub, you can add your vote [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4059).